# How to get the aggregated sum group by from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Input dictionary is as below, The output should be aggregated sum of item type
Input:

```
[{'item': 'item1', 'amount': 400},
 {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 300},
 {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 750}]
```

Output:

```
{'item1': 1150,
 'item2': 300}
```

Comment: It looks like you want to create a dictionary whose keys are the item names and whose values are the sums of the amounts for that item.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
sample_input = [{'item': 'item1', 'amount': 400}, {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 300}, {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 750}]
output = {}
for row in sample_input:
    if row['item'] in output:
         output[row['item']] += row['amount']
    else:
         output[row['item']] = row['amount']
```

This produces the desired output:

```
output = {'item1': 1150, 'item2': 300}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'item': 'item1', 'amount': 400},
 {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 300},
 {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 750}]

pd.DataFrame(data).groupby(['item']).agg(sum)['amount'].to_dict()
```